# Discord.js : How to delete the bot/client's message after it's sent?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to delete the client's message (sent using `` message.channel.send(`Cleared ${args[0]} messages`) ``) after 5 seconds, but I don't know how to do so. May someone help me with a code?

Here is my code:

```js
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'purge'){
        message.channel.bulkDelete(args[0]);
        message.channel.send(`Cleared ${args[0]} messages`)
        message.delete(message.author == client)
    };
});
```

I was trying to use the following code:

message.delete(client.message)

I am a beginner to discord.js, btw.

Comment: Not sure what you want to delete. The `Cleared ${args[0]} messages` message? Why do you send it if you want to delete it?

Comment: I just want to send the "Cleared ${args[0]} messages", and after like 5 seconds or so then delete it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete the message you sent, you can use the return value of the `send()` method. If you want to do this after 5 seconds, you can set a timer using `setTimeout`.

`.send()` returns a promise. You can use async/await to grab that message so you can delete it later.

I would also check the number of deleted messages, as `args[0]` won't always be the same as the number of messages. And you should really check if `args[0]` is valid; check if it's a numeric value, check if it's less than 100, etc.

```js
client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === 'purge') {
    // you should really check if args[0] is valid!
    const deletedMessages = await message.channel.bulkDelete(args[0]);
    const sentMessage = await message.channel.send(
      `Cleared ${deletedMessages.size} messages`,
    );

    setTimeout(() => {
      sentMessage.delete();
    }, 5000);
  }
});
```